# TYPO3 Extbase field names with numbers

Tags: typo3, extbase

I’ve got problematic use case:

I’ve got a field `something_10_somotherthing` in my database, and it seems that extbase experiences some issues mapping `$something10Someotherthing` to this field, though I don’t know why.

I’m importing the data from a json file into my mysql database 1:1 and mapping it with extbase afterwards, so I’m not that flexible on field names (but I could implement a mapping in my import if needed). I tried mapping the field using the techniques from the documentation (https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/8.7/6-Persistence/4-use-foreign-data-sources.html) but even when adding this to `ext_typoscript_setup.txt` and `ext_typoscript_setup.typoscript`, nothing happened. Any thoughts?

I think I’ve got an issue because of the `10` and that extbase might not be able to map it properly to a `lowerCamelCase` name but really unsure about it.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi as your property can not automatically maped bacause of the `_10_` part. You havr two options

1. Define an explicit property mapping see https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/6-Persistence/4-use-foreign-data-sources.html
2. Rename your fieldname to `something10_somotherthing`

Explanation: expbase uses upercase letters as seperators to generate the field name. And numbers are lowercase. So it does not insert an underscore seperator thus ending with field name `something10_somotherthing`

Comment: I actually had to remapp the field on import as I wasn't able to get anything other to work. Thansk @Wolffc